# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.faces.util.Util.isCdiOneOneOrGreater()Z

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I tried to start web project in jboss using jsf2.2 but the following error occurs:

```
12:11:40,640 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."SuperScreen.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."SuperScreen.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "SuperScreen.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.faces.util.Util.isCdiOneOneOrGreater()Z
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeExtension.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.WeldPortableExtensions.tryRegisterExtension(WeldPortableExtensions.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:119)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: As described here: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/241431?start=0&tstart=0, you might need to exclude the existing JSF implementation provided by JBoss, so that it won't conflict with the one you are providing. To get more help, please specify the JBoss version, and your maven pom file (or your dependencies).

Comment: I have already tried that link but there occurs another error. I am using JbossEAP 6.1 server

Comment: @Gibi, you should follow the indications depicted [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jsf/installing-jsf-22-on-jboss-as-7), since JBoss AS 7 is the community version of JBoss EAP 6.