# Multiple JSF related files in Weblogic modules folder

Tags: jsf, weblogic

I have recently installed the WebLogic 12.1.3 on my local windows 10 desktop. Created a very small webapp and it ran fine until I added the beans.xml.
Adding the beans.xml and starting the server, **I get the error : weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.faces.util.Util.isCdiOneOneOrGreater()Z** 
I could sort of understand it is something related to a mismatch in JSF versions. Then, I started searching and stumbled upon this beautiful answer from BalusC.
[How to find out the current version of Mojarra which my WebLogic is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083068/how-to-find-out-the-current-version-of-mojarra-which-my-weblogic-is-using)
The above answer says "Another way would be to explore the JSF module in /wlserver/modules folder of WebLogic installation. In my 12c installation, the filename says glassfish.jsf_1.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar, which in turn identifies Mojarra 2.1.20".
So I checked to see what is there in my modules folder and I got more than 1 jsf jar. My question (preferably to BalusC :-) but also to anyone who can help) is 
 - if it is fine or not to have multiple JSF related jars in the modules folder.
 - if this multiple JSF jars is the reason for the error ? 
 - if I can clean up (manually delete) files in this "modules" folder to have one version of JSF related files ?

**Note** : All these stuff came out of the box with the 12.1.3 installation.

### JSF related files found in my "\wlserver\modules" folder

- glassfish.jsf_1.2.0.0_1-2-15.jar
- glassfish.jsf_2.0.0.0_2-1-20.jar
- javax.jsf_1.4.0.0_1-2.jar
- weblogic.server.modules.jsf_12.1.3.0.jar
- weblogic.server.modules.jsf2.0_12.1.3.0.jar
- weblogic.server.merge.modules_12.1.3.0.xml
- weblogic.server.modules.extra_12.1.3.0.xml
- weblogic.server.modules.jsf_12.1.3.0.xml
- weblogic.server.modules.jsf2.0_12.1.3.0.xml

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: _"I get the error : com.sun.faces.util.Util.isCdiOneOneOrGreater() "_ This is not an error but a method name in a class. What is the actual error?

Comment: @Kukeltje, Thanks for your comment. Sorry about missing the complete error. I just corrected it.

Comment: The answer is still valid for your actual questions!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using JSF and JSTL With Web Applications:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WBAPP/configurejsfandjtsl.htm#WBAPP197

it will depend if you are embedding the JSF jar's.
I think you need to upgrade JSF, embedding the jars and using Filtering Classloading.

```
<prefer-application-packages> 
   <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name> 
   <package-name>com.sun.faces.*</package-name> 
   <package-name>com.bea.faces.*</package-name> 
   </prefer-application-packages> 

   <prefer-application-resources> 
   <resource-name>javax.faces.*</resource-name> 
   <resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</resource-name> 
   <resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</resource-name> 

<resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</resource-name>
<resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.*</resource-name>
   </prefer-application-resources>
```

It looks similar (jboss) to: [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.faces.util.Util.isCdiOneOneOrGreater()Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880840/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-sun-faces-util-util-iscdioneoneorgreaterz?noredirect=1&lq=1)